# If $T^2$ is a compact operator on a Banach space then is $T$ also compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compact-operators

> If $T^2$ is a compact operator on a Banach space $X$ then is it true that $T$ is also compact operator on X?

Here $T:X\to X.$

First I was trying to prove(assuming it is true). Since $X$ is Banach the set of all compact operators is  closed  in $\beta(X;X)$ ($\beta(X;X)$ is the set of all bounded operators in X). So I was trying to find a sequence $\{T_n\}$ in $\beta_0(X;X)$ (the set of all compact operators on $X$) which would converge to $T$ . Then using the given condition that $T^2\in\beta_0(X;X)$, we could say that $T\in \beta(X;X)$.

So the main point is to find a suitable sequence $\{T_n\}$ from $\beta_0(X;X)$ that will converge to $T.$

Please someone help . Can we find such sequence or the statement is false?

Thank you..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not true. Take, for instance $T\colon\ell^\infty\longrightarrow\ell^\infty$ defined by$$T(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6,\ldots)=(a_2,0,a_4,0,a_6,0,\ldots).$$Then $T$ is not compact (with respect to the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm), but $T^2=0$, which, of course, is compact.

Comment: Here we have to show that $\overline{T(B(0,1))}$ is not compact. Clearly $B(0,1)=\{0\}$ and hence $\overline{T(B(0,1))}=\{0\}\in l^{\infty}(\mathbb N_0)$. Don't know where am I doing wrong.

Comment: @mathiu_lady What makes you think that $B(0,1)=\{0\}$? It is not. For instance,$$\left(\frac12,\frac12,\frac12,\ldots\right)\in B(0,1).$$

Comment: But $a_1,a_2,...$ must belong to $\mathbb N$ , right?

Comment: @mathiu_lady Wrong. $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ is the set of all bounded  functions from $\mathbb N$ into $\mathbb C$. That is, it is the set of all bounded sequences of complex numbers.

Comment: Here we use this notation $l^{\infty}(\mathbb K)$ for your notation. Thank you.

Comment: @mathiu_lady I'm sorry about the confusion and I've edited my answer.